# Phonegap Plugin for flurry Ads

Tags: cordova, flurry

The flurry Sdk for ios is not working in my phonegap app.Its not showing any error.It works fine in android  but not in ios.I used https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-flurry this plugin which is the only plugin available.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is tested on device and emulator, and it works on Android and iOS.

I am the author of the plugin, and I wanna provide help. Please create a issue tracker with detailed info, so that I can find some clue.

GitHub issue tracker is a good place to get support for corresponding projects.
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-flurry/issues

A "good" bug report may include following info:

1. your steps to re-produce the error.
2. error log.
3. screenshot, if possible.

How to get error log:

- for android app, import the project into eclipse, build and run, you will see the log in eclipse LogCat window.
- for ios app, import the project into xcode, build and run, you will see the log in Xcode log window.

Please provide useful info, and I will be glad to support.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertAction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFlurryAds_5.4.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFlurryAds_5.4.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) i am getting this error after including flurry plugin i ma not been able to build ios app from terminal

Comment: is this plugin works with ios sdk 7.1? What i found that this plugin require xcode 6 and ios 8 to run.Please confirm  as soon as possible?

Comment: i googled "UIAlertController", and found this class is introduced in iOS8. so you have to upgrade to iOS8 SDK.

Comment: So what you are suggesting me?

Comment: as mentioned above, as the class is referenced by Flurry SDK, you have to upgrade to iOS8 SDK.

Comment: HI i have changed the flurry sdk to 5.3 version .NOW it builds properly  but when i run the app crashes#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
} in this code what is the problem i am not getting it please help ..

Comment: i think the problem is, the plugin is build with sdk 5.4, link to sdk 5.3 may not work properly. just guess, not very sure.

Comment: I implemented that natively.                                       Thanks For the help